# Passing variable in closure into imported function

Tags: javascript

The title doesn't really make sense. But I can't think of a better one, so pardon me...
Consider this.

I am trying to move the definition of `handleFBResp` out of the callback into its own module. But tricky thing is, I need to use `dispatch`, which is only accessible from the closure.

I can't use the `bind` trick either because it creates a new function, and the `removeListener` wouldn't work.

What's the appropriate way here?

```
(action) => (dispatch, getState) => {
chrome.tabs.create({
  url: FB_OAUTH_URI
}, (tab) => {
  // I would like this function definition to be extracted 
  // into its own module, and import it.
  function handleFBResp(tabId, tabObj, _) {
    if (typeof tabObj.url !== 'undefined') {
      let matchedCode = tabObj.url.match(/code=(.+)/);
      if (matchedCode) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(handleFBResp);
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);

        fbLogin(matchedCode[1]);

        dispatch ...
      }
    }
  }

  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleFBResp);
  // this below wouldn't work because bind creates a new function, 
  // and removeListener won't work
  // chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleFBResp.bind(null, dispatch));
}
```

Comment: I need to add `handleFBResp` as a listener. In order to pass `dispatch` in, I need to do `bind`. But that would make `removeListener` not work

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you are not the caller. I had missed the last bit of the code at first. Is still the basic solution. Hold on a moment,.

Comment: @barry-johnson just figured it out.. haha, thanks for helping. your comment actually inspired me :D

Comment: Oh, and now I see with your `removeListener` why you can't even use partial/bind to get this sorted easily. That is a little hairy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, figured this out. Here's what I do

I first make the `handleFbResp` as a thunk, and extract that into a module

```
export function handleFbResp(dispatch) {

  return function _handleFbResp(tabId, tabObj) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(_handleFbResp);
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
  }
}
```

Then I add the listener and invoke the thunk.

```
(action) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: FB_OAUTH_URI
  }, (tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleFbResp(dispatch));
  }
}
```

Comment: @barry-johnson yeah, thanks a lot. you question just struck me and reminded me I can make a thunk!